# Dynamic buttons in jQuery Mobile footer?

Tags: jquery-mobile

Dynamically injecting buttons into JQM footers seems to be an exercise in frustration. Anyone have a clue how to apply proper formatting for this? Here are several anomalies I found trying to do this:

- Multi-column button grids are not properly formatted in the footer
- data-corners="false" attribute (to get flush buttons) does not apply to the first and last buttons in the footer
- With data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" for the footer buttons, if there are too many buttons to fit in one row the styling looks weird (since some buttons will have rounded corners, others will not)
- If data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" are omitted for the footer buttons, buttons may be rendered partially off the screen...

In general - argh!!!! Anyone have any success dynamically injecting buttons into a footer? If so, would much appreciate to hear how this was achieved.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Multi-column button grids are not properly formatted in the footer - this is my response to that.

One thing to check if you are using controlgroup with a href links -  make sure your each  of the links in the control group has the following CSS;

```
vertical-align:top;
```

You will also have to get more control over how the elements look if you are styling them as buttons. I posted a similar discussion over here:

https://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-mobile-horizontal-control-groups-creating-a-custom-split-list

https://forum.jquery.com/topic/css-code-to-help-control-entire-button-in-a-jquery-mobile-theme

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Would something like this work:

- http://jsfiddle.net/eznh8/7/

JS

```
$('#addButtonName').click(function() {
    var theFooter = $('#addMoreButtons');
    var buttonName= $('#newButtonName');

    if(buttonName.val() != '') {
        theFooter.append('<a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="delete">'+buttonName.val()+'</a>');
        buttonName.val('');
        $('#theHomePage').trigger('create');  
    }
});
```

HTML

```
<div data-role="page" id="theHomePage">
    <label for="basic">Button Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="newButtonName" id="newButtonName" value="" />
    <a href="#" data-role="button" id="addButtonName">Add New button</a>
    <div data-role="footer" class="ui-bar" id="addMoreButtons">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. I guess I am just running into a few idiosyncrasies with buttons in footers in general - and attributed it to my dynamic changes. What I am seeing now is that footer buttons can sometimes overflow a bit to the right of the screen - you can see it easily if you gradually resize the result JQM panel. This does not happen with regular inline buttons in the body (just tried it). Additionally, I had a pre-defined button in my html, and added more dynamically. It turns out that JQM puts more space after the first predefined footer button, but not if that button is inserted dynamically...hmmm

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mokesmokes/8VS7F/  Gradually resize the JQM panel width and see the ugliness on the right side in the footer (last character in right-most button gets chopped). This would happen to me when dynamically adding buttons.

Comment: Maybe add some padding? viewpoint? I will play around with it, Another example: http://jsfiddle.net/eznh8/8/

Comment: In the example I gave in my previous comment, class="ui-bar" is the culprit. If you remove this class from the footer there is no overflow to the right. As to your latest example - just checking that you see the extra padding after the first button - right?